# Subclassing rv_continuous in SciPy 0.8.0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to perform a fit to some data using a "Double Gaussian" (i.e. the normalized sum of two normal distributions). Using SciPy 0.18.1, the following code works:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

class DoubleGauss(rv_continuous):
    """Double Gaussian distribution"""

    def _pdf(self, x, mu1, sigma1, mu2, sigma2, w):
        g1 = np.exp(-0.5*((x-mu1)/sigma1)**2) / np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi*sigma1**2)
        g2 = np.exp(-0.5*((x-mu2)/sigma2)**2) / np.sqrt(2.0*np.pi*sigma2**2)
        return w * g1 + (1.0-w) * g2

dg = DoubleGauss(name='DG')
print dg.rvs(mu1=0.001, sigma1=2.0, mu2=0.05, sigma2=4.0, w=0.8)
```

(This is of course a minimal example. In the end, I will also redefine _cdf for speed and _argcheck to allow for non-zero values of the mu parameters.)

Because I need to read the data to be fitted using some other librarys, I have to run the code in an environment with only SciPy 0.8.0 available. Running the same code, however, results in this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print dg.rvs(mu1=0.01, sigma1=2.0, mu2=0.05, sigma2=4.0, w=0.8)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 523, in rvs
    vals = self._rvs(*args)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 848, in _rvs
    Y = self._ppf(U,*args)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 861, in _ppf
    return self.vecfunc(q,*args)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-numpy/1.6.1-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1862, in __call__
    theout = self.thefunc(*newargs)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 817, in _ppf_single_call
    return optimize.brentq(self._ppf_to_solve, self.xa, self.xb, args=(q,)+args, xtol=self.xtol)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 362, in brentq
    r = _zeros._brentq(f,a,b,xtol,maxiter,args,full_output,disp)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 814, in _ppf_to_solve
    return apply(self.cdf, (x, )+args)-q
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 952, in cdf
    place(output,cond,self._cdf(*goodargs))
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 855, in _cdf
    return self.veccdf(x,*args)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-numpy/1.6.1-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1862, in __call__
    theout = self.thefunc(*newargs)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 852, in _cdf_single_call
    return scipy.integrate.quad(self._pdf, self.a, x, args=args)[0]
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 247, in quad
    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
  File "/cvmfs/cms.cern.ch/slc6_amd64_gcc491/external/py2-scipy/0.8.0-cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 313, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: _pdf() takes exactly 7 arguments (2 given)
```

In the documentation, I find no differences in the description of how to use rv_continuous. How can I fix the code such that it works with SciPy 0.8.0?

Comment: Scipy 0.8. Wow. First guess: prior to 0.13.0, pdf et al did not accept keyword arguments. Try giving them as positional args?

Comment: I needed to think a bit about what you mean, but it works. I just need to do `print dg.rvs(0.01, 2.0, 0.05, 4.0, 0.8)` to get a running code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to 0.13, pdf et al did not accept keyword arguments. Try giving them as positional args, rather than keyword (named) arguments.

There have been several other improvements since v0.8, too. I *think* you need to specify the shapes in the constructor, also there was something callef xa and xb for ppf --- you may want to check the sources at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.8.0/scipy/stats/distributions.py